# Webcam only works when I lock and unlock smartphone

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webrtc, webrtc-android

I'm doing a simple demo app in Flutter using the [flutter_webrtc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc) plugin following [this](https://www.100ms.live/blog/flutter-webrtc#resources) tutorial. When I test using Chrome its works just fine, in emulator the camera image never shows, and when I test on my Android smartphone the camera image only appears when I lock (power button) and unlock (power button again) the device.

I am using Windows 11, Android Studio 2022.1.1 Patch 1, Flutter 3.7.5, Dart 2.19.1 OpenJDK 19.0.2 and flutter_webrtc 0.9.23.

Right now my code is the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _localVideoRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();

  void initRenderers() async {
    await _localVideoRenderer.initialize();
  }

  _getUserMedia() async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> mediaConstraints = {
      'audio': true,
      'video': true,
    };

    MediaStream stream =
    await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
    _localVideoRenderer.srcObject = stream;

    _localVideoRenderer.srcObject = stream;
    return stream;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initRenderers();
    _getUserMedia();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    await _localVideoRenderer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ButtonStyle style =
    ElevatedButton.styleFrom(textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20));


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
              top: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              left: 0.0,
              bottom: 0.0,
              child: RTCVideoView(_localVideoRenderer))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I already tried to test on multiple platforms, already tried to invoke the method to show the camera image on a button and aready tried to use another tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related to flutter state management, I added:

```
setState(() {
});
```

After `srcObject = stream` and it works!